# REST Request to Ignite using c++

Tags: c++, rest, ignite

I am trying to use Ignite to store the table in cache using C++. We are using REST API for requesting the data. I have configured the xml like this

```
<property name="connectorConfiguration">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">
<property name="host" value="localhost"/>
<property name="port" value="8085"/>
</bean>
</property>
```

And send a request using curl

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8085/ignite?cmd=version
```

But the response i got like this `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` .How can i cache the data using REST POST request?

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectorConfiguration.port` is not responsible for REST API port. You can specify it using JETTY_REST_PORT JVM parameter:

```
$ JVM_OPTS='-DIGNITE_JETTY_PORT=8085' ignite.sh
```

It can also be changed in Jetty configuration. Path to Jetty configuration file can be specified using `ConnectorConfiguration.jettyPath` property.

Comment: In JAVA we have a class named `ConnectorConfiguration`. But in c++ i don't found any class similar to this.

Comment: You can configure connector in Ignite XML configuration, you don't need a C++ class for it.